# custom exceptions are wrapped in weblogic

Tags: exception, weblogic

this application is migrated from oc4j to weblogic. almost all functionalities are working fine.

we are throwing CBCMException  which is a sub class of RuntimeException. when certain scenarios occurs.

in oc4j we used to get the error message as what we specify like 
Kindly apply more specific criteria to your search condition in order to view your search results...]

But in weblogic this exception is wrapped under java.rmi.RemoteException: and we not getting the CBCMException

is there any way to get the origianl Exception we throw, other then modifying the supercalss to Exception.

this exception is throwed extensively in our project.

> java.rmi.RemoteException: EJB Exception: ; nested exception is:
>   CBCMException [errorCode=Kindly apply more specific criteria to your
>   search condition in order to view your search results...] at
>   weblogic.ejb.container.internal.EJBRuntimeUtils.throwRemoteException(EJBRuntimeUtils.java:106)
>   at
>   weblogic.ejb.container.internal.BaseRemoteObject.handleSystemException(BaseRemoteObject.java:857)
>   at
>   weblogic.ejb.container.internal.BaseRemoteObject.handleSystemException(BaseRemoteObject.java:809)
>   at
>   weblogic.ejb.container.internal.BaseRemoteObject.postInvoke1(BaseRemoteObject.java:518)
>   at
>   weblogic.ejb.container.internal.StatelessRemoteObject.postInvoke1(StatelessRemoteObject.java:49)
>   at
>   weblogic.ejb.container.internal.BaseRemoteObject.__WL_postInvokeTxRetry(BaseRemoteObject.java:444)
>   at
>   weblogic.ejb.container.internal.SessionRemoteMethodInvoker.invoke(SessionRemoteMethodInvoker.java:53)
>   at
>   ae.co.etisalat.cbcm.app.util.search.impl.SearchEJB_siuh74_EOImpl.selectMatchingRecords(Unknown
>   Source) at
>   ae.co.etisalat.cbcm.web.util.search.SearchModel.selectMatchingRecords(Unknown
>   Source) at
>   ae.co.etisalat.cbcm.web.util.search.struts.SearchAction.searchResults(Unknown
>   Source) at
>   ae.co.etisalat.cbcm.web.util.search.struts.SearchAction.execute(Unknown
>   Source) at
>   org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:484)
>   at
>   org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:274)
>   at
>   org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1482)
>   at
>   org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:525)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727) at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820) at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
>   at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
>   at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:300)
>   at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
>   at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
>   at
>   ae.co.etisalat.cbcm.web.util.auditing.SessionFilter.doFilter(Unknown
>   Source) at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
>   at ae.co.etisalat.cbcm.web.util.security.LoginFilter.doFilter(Unknown
>   Source) at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
>   at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3715)
>   at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3681)
>   at
>   weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
>   at
>   weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
>   at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2277)
>   at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2183)
>   at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1454)
>   at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:209) at
>   weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:178) Caused by:
>   CBCMException [errorCode=Kindly apply more specific criteria to your
>   search condition in order to view your search results...] at
>   ae.co.etisalat.cbcm.biz.util.search.persistencymapping.SearchManager.selectMatchingRecords(Unknown
>   Source) at
>   ae.co.etisalat.cbcm.app.util.search.helper.SearchHelper.selectMatchingRecords(Unknown
>   Source) at
>   ae.co.etisalat.cbcm.app.util.search.impl.SearchEJBBean.selectMatchingRecords(Unknown
>   Source) at

thanks for your time and reply.

regards
Muthuvel.P

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the problem by adding `@ApplicationException` in the class and adding exception class name in the `<assembly descriptor>`.